# Wordpress page links after GoDaddy addon domain

Tags: wordpress, dns

I built a website for our company using a wordpress install. This is installed in it's own directory on our hosting account on GoDaddy. We have a domain purchased through GoDaddy added as an addon domain. When you go to OurNewSite.com you see the homepage located at OurOldSite.com/wordpress, and OurNewSite.com in the address bar. However, when you navigate to the About Us page on the site, the address bar changes back to OurOldSite.com/wordpress/about.

I've tried the answer from [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076890/mask-a-forwarded-url-to-wordpress-in-a-directory) here, with OurNewSite.com in the fields, but this doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds very much like a DNS update / firewall issue to me. It is very likely that the DNS changes were not regocnized behind the firewall yet. I've had that issue once: it took like 1 week to get the changes updated behind the FW. The solution in my case was *to wait*. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was wondering about the update time as well. Did you need to make the changes to the .htaccess file as suggested in the post I linked to?

Comment: Nope, as I said - I've just waited for around 1 week. Our tyreshop was losing lots of money, everybody was freakin' out. Support hotline calls all day, googling all day.. Everything was correct - the solution was *to wait*. You can try to delete your browser cache by CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE (all browsers) and delete cache.

Comment: Guess the waiting game begins then... Thanks!

Comment: No problem, keep calm and keep coding ;) good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is actually what worked for me. After waiting, the link eventually updated after a few hours, but it produced an Internal Server Error. [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/) has a list of common causes for the error I was getting on the link pages. The directions for "checking for a corrupt .htaccess file worked like a charm.